# Pusher can't trigger an event in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pusher

javascribe to subscribe channel is given below .Channel Subscribed properly.

```
 var pusher = new Pusher('Appkey', { cluster: 'ap2'});
 var channel = pusher.subscribe('publisher-token-from-javascript');
```

Method to trigger an event

```
$pusher = new Pusher('$key', '$secret', '$id', $options);

$response = $pusher->trigger('my-channel0000', 'my-event', array('message' => 'hello world'));
```

Pusher code always return null in response

```
array (size=2)
  'body' => boolean false
  'status' => int 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pusher library of CodeIgniter is not updated when connecting to alternative cluster. The old library always connects to (default: http://api.pusherapp.com) host. To fix your problem you have to make sure the credentials are correct.

To quickly fix your problem check if you can configure $config['pusher_host'] on your server side config to : **http://api-[yourcluster].pusher.com**

*Example*

```
$config['pusher_api_key'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$config['pusher_secret'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$config['pusher_app_id'] = 'XXXXXX'; 
$config['pusher_host'] = 'http://api-eu.pusher.com';
```